# BASH: pass arguments to sub-script

Tags: shell-script, configuration, variable

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

. config

./sub-script
```

There are a lot of variables in config and I don't want to pass them to sub-scirpt like `./subscript arg1 arg2 ... arg100500`.
Also, I don't like an idea to `source` config from sub-script, because in general it may not know where there config file resides.

Is there any other way to make config available in sub-script?

Comment: @the_velour_fog, but they don't. Just checked it.

Comment: What about if you just use `source /path/to/sub-script` ? can you try that?

Comment: @the_velour_fog, that way it works, thanks.

Comment: You could pass the full pathname of the config file to the sub-script, e.g.  `./sub-script /path/to/config`.  the sub-script could then do something like `cfg="$1" ; shift ; . "$cfg"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `export` your variables:

```
 VAR=foo
 export VAR
```

or:

```
 export VAR=foo
```

However, these variables will be visible in the environment of all subprocesses.

Comment: that is what I was looking for. thnx

Answer (score 3):

If you can set your script up this way

```
#!/bin/bash

. config

. /path/to/sub-script
```

Any variables initialised in `config` should become available to the main script and any scripts it sources.

#### Explanation

It seems your script was launching a new non-interactive shell process, shell variables initialised in the parent script would not have been available - but exported environment variables should be available to the new child process.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the full pathname of the config file to the sub-script. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./config

./sub-script ./config
```

The sub-script could then do something like this:

```
cfg="$1"
shift
. "$cfg"
```

You could even have a default for `$cfg`, just in case `$1` is empty.

```
cfg=${1:-/path/to/default/config}
```